# Basis of weight lattice in terms of root lattice

Tags: representation-theory, integer-lattices, root-systems

Let $\Lambda_R = \bigoplus_{i \in I}  \mathbb{Z} \cdot \alpha_i$ be the root lattice of a root system $\Phi$ with simple roots $\alpha_i$ and let $\Lambda_W$ denote the corresponding weight lattice. Is there a way to compute the reals $q_i \leq 1$, s.t. $\Lambda_W = \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z} \cdot (q_i\alpha_i)$? They should exist, right? At least in the $B_n$-case, they should be $\frac{1}{2}, \dots, \frac{1}{2},1$.

Comment: The weight lattice is just the dual lattice of the root lattice, so all you have to do is find a basis for the dual lattice. For Euclidean inner product if the columns of the matrix M give a basis for the root lattice, the rows of $M^{-1}$ will give the basis for the weight lattice.

Comment: So, I'm not looking for the dual basis  but one, s.t. $\lambda_i =q_i\alpha_i$